# QtConcurrent::run() calling another class method

Tags: c++11, qt5, unique-ptr, qtconcurrent

I am trying to use QTConcurrent class to launch some tasks asynchronously but I am getting some errors:

This is my code:

```
class A {
  public:
  void method1();
};
class B {
 std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
 public:
  void method2() {
     QtConcurrent::run(&this->ptr, &A::method1);
  }
}
```

I get compilation error.

Could someone tell me what the correct syntax is?

Thanks in advance and regards

Comment: Class `B` doesn't have a member named `_xdmService`. The name `PttpXdmService` is not declared. No wonder you get compilation errors with this example.

Answer (score 0):

I finally was able to find working version:

```
class A {
 public:
 void method1();
};
class B {
  std::unique_ptr<A> ptr;
 public:
  void method2() {
    QtConcurrent::run(this->ptr.get(), &A::method1);
  }
}
```